# Scala type check fails unexpectedly for case class with higher-kinded type parameter in pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typechecking, type-parameter, higher-kinded-types

Let me define some types

```
trait H
trait Gen[h <: H]
trait Gen2[h <: H] extends Gen[h]

trait Ez[g[h <: H] <: Gen[h]] // needs to be invariant

case class CC[g[h <: H] <: Gen[h], E[g[h <: H] <: Gen[h]] <: Ez[g]](i: E[g])
```

A custom extractor to workaround https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5900

```
object CCX {
  def unapply[g[h <: H] <: Gen[h], E[g[h <: H] <: Gen[h]] <: Ez[g]](i: CC[g, E]): Option[E[g]] = ???
}
```

And its usecase

```
// not compiles
(null: AnyRef) match {
  case CCX(i: Ez[Gen2]) =>
}
```

At compile time using Scala 2.10.4, I got the following error

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
     found   : Ez[Gen2]
     required: Ez[g] where type g[h <: H] <: Gen[h]
          case CCX(i: Ez[Gen2]) =>
                      ^
```

But `Ez[Gen2]` seems to conform to `Ez[g]` as in

```
// these compiles
val i: Ez[Gen2] = ???
val cc = CC(i)
val u: Option[Ez[Gen2]] = CCX.unapply(cc)
```

I'm wondering if it is a bug. Ortherwise, could you please explain the the reason or links to some resources?